# Rails: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound exception the best way to handle the Exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am absolutely new to rails.please help me.

What are possibilities we can handle this kind of Exception.
as Rails offer multiple choices to find record. but some time it becomes difficult to find the best one.

**SO**

in this controller to get records against `id`

```
class Api::ShowController < ApplicationController
      def get
        id = params[:id]
       # render json: id and return
        if id != nil
          @post = Post.find(id)
        else
          @posts = Post.all
        end
          render json: @posts
      end
    end
```

it shows:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Api::ShowController#get

error is at this line

> @post = Post.find(id)

Comment: you should stick to REST conventions

Comment: I am new in ROR, can you suggest me web page ?

Comment: The standard rails approach is to have 7 methods in your controller for the CRUD (create, review, updated and delete) functionality. These are called index, show, new, create, edit, update and destroy. For more information, read about it here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have to do some changes:

```
def get
  if params[:id].present?
    @post = Post.find_by(id: params[:id])
    if @post.nil?
      render json: { 
        :success => false,
        :message => "Post not found."
      }
    else
      render json: @post
    end
  else
    @posts = Post.all
    render json: @posts
  end
end
```

NOTE: for Rails 4 `find_by_id` will deprecated future so you have to use `find_by(id: params id)`. Below the link:

[rails 4 deprecations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations)

Answer (score 1):

What this means is that there is no Post record in your database with an ID of 3. `Post.find()` will return an error if it can't find a post with the id requested. You could instead use `Post.find_by_id()` which will return a null object, but then you need to handle all the things that Post can do that Nil can not.

Here's a couple of things you may wish to change here.

- Error handling when records are not found, you may wish to return some specific JSON when the post you're looking for does not exist.
- You are creating one of two attributes, @post or @posts, but trying to render a json version of @posts. This will be nil if a post was found.
- As discussed in the comment chain, a standard Rails approach is to have an index method to return all records, and a show method to return a single record.

Comment: yeh, it works,

do I need to create method to find all posts in `index` action, and a new method to show single post in `show` action

Comment: That's the typical REST way, yes.